# My code exceeds the amount of times i want it to loop

Tags: c, loops, while-loop

i wrote a c code in c to display the square cubed of 50, the loop works but it stops at 150 instead of 100. what did i do wrong?

```
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int n=50;
    int i=0; //column names Number Square and Cube 
    printf("Number\tSquare\tCube\n");
    printf("____________________________\n");

    while (i<=100)
    {
        printf("%d\t%d\t%d\n", n, n * n, n * n * n);
        i++;
        n++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `i` starts at 0 and goes to 100. `n` starts at 50 and goes to 150. I'm not sure what you're asking about.

Comment: i want to display the square and cubed of numbers from 50-100, its doing 50-150 instead

Comment: Why do you have `i` at all?

Comment: Then either change `while (i<=100)` to `while (i<=50)` or use the value of `n` as your loop condition and get rid of `i` completely.

Comment: Make `n` your loop counter and remove `i`;

Comment: @RetiredNinja that prints the square and cubed of 50 only

Comment: It doesn't, unless whatever you changed broke something. https://godbolt.org/z/dnYTnWr4K

Answer (score 0):

You said

> i want to display the square and cubed of numbers from 50-100, its doing 50-150 instead

So one solution is to change your `while` loop condition so that it stops after `n` reaches 100:

```
while (n<=100)
```

After you make this change and verify that your program produces the correct output, you may notice that you no longer need the `i` variable at all.